# C++ программа которая выводит на экран количество простых чисел среди введённых

Tags: c++, циклы, условия, простые-числа, теория-чисел

Пользователь вводит в с клавиатуры десять чисел больше двух, нужно что бы программа выводила количество простых чисел среди введённых

Понимаю что код не правильный, но нужна максимально простая программа, может кто-то может подсказать как это исправить

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  cout<<("Введите 10 чисел больше двух");
  int a;
  int i =0;
  int k=0;
  int kolichestvo =0;
  for (int j=1;j<10;j++)
    {
      cin>>a;
      for (int i;i<=a;i++)
      {
        if (a%i==0) 
        {
            k=k+1;
        } 
        if (k>2)
        {
            kolichestvo+=1;
  
       }} 
   
   } 
  cout<<kolichestvo;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот, 14 часов без электричества из-за утреннего обстрела "очень военной" ТЭЦ закончились, так что могу наконец ответить, что называется, сидя на броне горящего танка...

Вот более-менее эффективно работающий код.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Введите 10 чисел больше двух: ";
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0, n; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        cin >> n;
        if (n%2 == 0) continue;  // Отдельная проверка четности
        bool is_prime = true;
        for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2) // проверка только нечетных делителей
        {
            if (n%i == 0)
            {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_prime) ++count;
    }
    cout << "Простых чисел: " << count;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа, большое спасибо — щелчка там же на "птичке" — принятие ответа.